# R - RMySQL dbWriteTable Error

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I received the following error message when I try to output data from R to MySQL by dbWriteTable:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ 
for signature ‘"MySQLConnection", "grouped_df", "character"’
```

What I have written in R script is:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='pass', dbname='testdb', host='localhost')
Tester1 <- dbGetQuery(conn = mydb, statement ="select * from testtable)
Result1 <- Tester1 %>%
group_by(A,B,C,D,E) %>%
mutate(RunningTotal=cumsum(MeasureValue))
dbWriteTable(con=mydb,"testtable2",Result1, row.names=T, overwrite=T)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe try to add `%>% ungroup()` after your mutate statement? Alternatively, try to use the package `DBI`, e.g. `DBI:dbWriteTable`.

Comment: Hi Thamas, many thanks. I tried ungroup() then it worked! Many thanks!